# Show all available columns even when there is no data

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a query used in SSRS that is to show all Client Names, the count of records, by each date. My problem is the query below only shows those that have data on that particular date. Many times a client may not have data for a few days or weeks, and this report only shows client having data. Can I show the full list of Clients even when they may return 0 records? I do not know if this is possible using my CTE setup.

Ex:

Client A: 0

Client B: 10

Client C: 0

Client D: 35

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;


WITH CTE AS (

select c.ClientName, convert(char(10), h.RecordDate, 120) As Date, COUNT(*) As Count
from clientHistory h 
inner join client c on c.ClientID = h.clientid
where convert(char(10), h.RecordDate, 120) > DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE())
group by c.ClientName, convert(char(10), h.RecordDate, 120)

)

select c.ClientName, Date, Sum(Count) As Count 
from CTE
group by c.ClientName, Date order by ClientName
```

Comment: I guess you could change to an outer join to show all clients in general. Not really sure how it would end up in SSRS though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve every client then select from the client table and left join the clientHistory table:

```
select c.ClientName, convert(char(10), h.RecordDate, 120) As Date, COUNT(*) As Count
from  client c
left join clientHistory h 
    on c.ClientID = h.clientid
    and convert(char(10), h.RecordDate, 120) > DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE())
group by c.ClientName, convert(char(10), h.RecordDate, 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need calender Table

```
;WITH calender
     AS (SELECT convert(date,'2014-01-01') AS dates  -- Replace with startdate
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(dd, 1, dates)
         FROM   calender
         WHERE  dates < '2014-12-31'), -- Replace with enddate
     CTE1
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT ClientName
                 FROM   client) a
                CROSS JOIN calender),
     cte2
     AS (SELECT c.ClientName,
                CONVERT(CHAR(10), h.RecordDate, 120) AS Date,
                Count(*)                             AS Count
         FROM   clientHistory h
                INNER JOIN client c
                        ON c.ClientID = h.clientid
         WHERE  CONVERT(CHAR(10), h.RecordDate, 120) > Dateadd(DAY, -15, Getdate())
         GROUP  BY c.ClientName,
                   CONVERT(CHAR(10), h.RecordDate, 120))
SELECT a.ClientName,
       a.Dates,
       Sum(Count) AS Count
FROM   CTE1 a
       LEFT JOIN cte2 b
              ON a.dates = b.Date
                 AND a.ClientName = b.ClientName
GROUP  BY a.ClientName,
          a.Dates
ORDER  BY ClientName 
Option (Maxrecursion 0)
```